# Rig of model in blender export fbx to unity than live streaming MVN mocap data, the location of model is wrong

Tags: rigging, export, unity

I am a new user for blender (Using Maya in the past).

This time I try to use blender to build up a model and rig it using the Armature Human(Mata-Rig).

[image]

Since it just a simple model like this.

[image]

I just parent it with bone by using pose mode Ctrl + P.

[image]

And than export it to fbx.

[image]

Import to unity and Humanoid it, add a Xs Live Animator component. Click play, the problem is show.

[image][image][image]

What's wrong that I make?

I have try to make it T-pose before export form blender, it give same result.

I have try to import the white one [which rig by maya] in blender and then export, it give same result.

I have try to change the export setting but it give same result.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please do not add "solved" as part of the title. If you found a solution for your problem please write it on the 
answers section and mark it as accepted there. Read: 
[what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)